# SQL find duplicates and assign group number

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation**
On a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 I have about 2 million rows. (this should have never happened but we inherited the situation). A sample as follows:

```
usernum. |  phone  |  email
1        |  123    |  user1@local.com
2        |  123    |  user2@local.com
3        |  245    |  user3@local.com
4        |  678    |  user3@local.com
```

**Aim**
I would like to create a table that looks like this. The idea is that if 'phone' or 'email' is the same, they are assigned the same group number.

```
groupnum |usernum. |  phone  |  email
1        |  1      |  123    |  user1@local.com
1        |  2      |  123    |  user2@local.com
2        |  3      |  245    |  user3@local.com
2        |  4      |  678    |  user3@local.com
```

**Tried so far**
So far I have created a simple python script that conceptually does the following:
- for each usernum in the table
-- assign a group number
-- also assign the group number to all rows where phone or email is the same as this row
-- do not assign the group number if usernum already processed (else we would do things double)
**Problem**
The python script basically has to check for each row if there are duplicates for phone or email. Although this is perfectly fine for maybe 10,000 records or so, it is too slow for 2 million records. I think this possible to do in t-sql which should be much faster than my python script using pyodbc. 
The big question thus is, how to do this in sql.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed you said email **or** phone is duplicate.  For that I would think you would need to decide which has priority in instances where a user could be joined from either field.  Or you could potentially just split the update into a few batches to make group numbers based on phone AND email, then email (when not already matched), then phone (when not already matched) as such:

```
insert into yourGroupsTable (phone, email) -- assuming identity column of groupNum here
select distinct phone, email
from yourUserTable

-- assign group nums with priority on matching phone AND email
update yourUserTable
set groupNum = g.groupNum
from yourUserTable u
join yourGroupsTable g on u.phone = g.phone
    and u.email = g.email
```

It occurs to me now that this would not work as each row would join on the yourGroupsTable due to the distinct select.  I came across a scenario that I'm unsure what your expected outcome would be (and too big for a comment) - what happens in this instance:

your test data slightly modified:

```
groupnum |usernum. |  phone  |  email
1        |  1      |  123    |  user1@local.com
1        |  2      |  123    |  user2@local.com
?        |  3      |  245    |  user3@local.com
?        |  4      |  678    |  user3@local.com
?        |  5      |  245    |  user7@local.com
?        |  6      |  678    |  user7@local.com
```

what would the group numbs be in the above case?

Answer (score 0):

As you do python script is good way ... if you want to move with mysql make it one procedure before inserting record must check its exist or not in table

If Exist 
    THEN get that row groupnum and assign that groupnum to this new record ... 
IF Not
    Then give new groupnum

**but i have still little confusion**

now if record is like

**5        | 678      | user1@local.com**

if this is the case then ?

I assume that both column [phone and email ] is consider to give groupnum.

if my assumption is correct then go with mysql procedure ...